# Can a Vector store more than one data in one position?

Tags: java, eclipse, vector

I have tried to find the related questions here. I think it is a common question but unlucky I still cannot find on the internet.

A point contains 3 parts, id , lat and lon. I used 3 separated vectors to store them but they are related to each other. When a new point is found, it has to add 3 times in different vectors...

I want to add 3 data into ONE vector rather than 3 separated vectors. Can Vector to do that ? or any other simple way to reach my goal ?

Many Thanks !

Here is my code:

```
public class Try01 {
  static Vector<String> id = new Vector<String>();
  static Vector<Double> lat = new Vector<Double>();
  static Vector<Double> lon = new Vector<Double>();

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
// create an input source for target document and parse it

  int counter=0;

  DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("data.xml"));

  // get all tags in the document with the name link
  NodeList links = doc.getElementsByTagName( "node" );

  for( int i = 0; i < links.getLength(); i++ ) {      
  Element link = (Element) links.item( i );
  //add part
  id.add(link.getAttribute( "id" ));
  lat.add( Double.parseDouble(link.getAttribute( "lat" )) );
  lon.add( Double.parseDouble(link.getAttribute( "lon" )) );

  //checking point: show the vector
  System.out.println( counter + " ) Vector = " + id.get(counter) + " and " + lat.get(counter) + " with " + lon.get(counter));

  counter++;     
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework. A hint - use objects.

Comment: Vector<Vector<Object>> but maybe there aren't reason use pre_mature Arrays type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store more than one "data" into a Vector position, but you can't store more than one "object". So the obvious solution is to use one "object" than can hold multiple "data". If you want to store location (latitude/longitude) into one single Vector position, create a class that modelates a location

```
class Location
{
    private String id = null;
    private double latitude = 0.0;
    private double longitude = 0.0;

    public Location(String id, double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public double getLongitude()
    {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude)
    {
        this.longitude = longitude
    }

    public double getLatitude()
    {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

and then store it into the Vector, like:

```
double lat, lon;
Vector<Location> vlocations = new Vector<Location>();
vlocations.add(new Location(lat, lon));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create a Vector of your own class, like `Vector<YourClass>` and this class holds all the 3 variables are its fields.

```
public class YourClass {
  String id;
  double lat;
  double lon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an class that can store the three parts of a point and then create a `Vector<Point>` to hold a collection of these objects.

Something like:

```
public class Point {
  private String id;
  private Double latitude;
  private Double longitude;

  //constructor, getters and setters, and rest of the class omitted
}
```

<s>On a side note, I don't think the use of `Vector`s is particularly encouraged anymore , so I would use a `List` such as an `ArrayList` instead: `List<Point> = new ArrayList<Point>`.</s> I just looked this up as I wasn't 100% sure, and here's a useful article explaining when to use each: [Vector or List](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/03-qa-0622-vector.html)

Answer (score 0):

We usually create separate classes and store instances of those to the vector:

```
public class Coordinate {
   public String id;
   public double lat;
   public double lon;
}
```

and later:

```
static Vector<Coordinate> coordinates = new Vector<Coordinate>();
```

and in the method:

```
Element link = (Element) links.item( i );
//add part
Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();
coord.id = link.getAttribute( "id" );
coord.lat = Double.parseDouble(link.getAttribute( "lat" ));
coord.lon = Double.parseDouble(link.getAttribute( "lon" ));
coordinates.add(coord);
```